# Visual Studio 2015 Emulator For Android Won't start/boot

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, hyper-v

Phone emulator works fine for me, but android emulator won't even boot.

I have tried repairing VS 2015, emulators, Hyper-V.

Seems like issue with the Windows 10. If i try to start virtual machine from Hyper-V, it displays console with last line has error that

"cannot read from dev/hw_random"

Any help or debug steps would be appreciated.

[Hyper v error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVoWL.png)

Comment: Hey @mubaidr -- the "cannot read from dev/hw_random" is a canary--it actually shows up on a successful boot. Could you give some more info on your system? What build of Win 10 and edition? What do you see in the emulator window (the black mobile phone "chrome") when this is happening? What if you start the emulator by going to the "Visual Studio Emulator for Android" under "Tools" in VS 2015?

Comment: There was no progress after that. But this thing is solved by updating Windows 10 build 10576. Now emulator works fine, both from within visual studio and direct launch. I think it was problem with the Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an error with the Windows 10 build 10565. When updated to Windows 10 build 10576, emulator successfully booted, without any additional requirements/fixes.